# Collaboration site and upload Email attachments to sharepoint

Tags: 2013, 2010, email, collaboration

I have requirement to upload documents which actually email attachments in SharePoint, from multiple departments and users from these departments upload documents and view only their documents,

1. for this approach which type of site collection template to use?
   how to organize all departments sites and users in one site collection?
2. For Email, attachments should upload on this site also?

Answer (score 1):

Site Collection: Template team site
Departments in different subsites with different securities.

Use the top level site to present the site/procedure, write guidance, ask for feedback or if you are able to, create a content search web part (if you have SP 2013) or content query web part (if you have 2010) to gather the contents which will be visible accordingly with permissions.

You can store email attachments, you can also enable the document library to receive emails, discharge the email message and keep the attachment, ask your exchange administrator if your SP is set up this way.

Comment: Hi in sharepoint 2010 either create Team site or document workspace ?

Comment: document workspace is very restrictive type of template, stick to the team site

Comment: Thanks, and if i enable incoming email settings to store email attachments in a list or doc library, how users can view attachments after they save in sharepoint?

Comment: just like normal documents. Emails do not open automatically, you need to download them first and double click on them or open the library in Explorer window. All the other docs behave like normal docs which have been uploaded